# Facebook Like button not working for all URLs

Tags: facebook-like

I'm trying to fix a problem with the Facebook like button not showing on some urls on our site. It was working fine on all URLs until about a week ago.

It seems to be pretty inconsistent.

Currently i can see the `like` button on this URL

http://www.chargrilled.co.uk/t-shirts/I-See-Dumb-People-t-shirt.m

But not this URL

http://www.chargrilled.co.uk/t-shirts/Tea-Is-For-Mugs-t-shirt.m

From testing I have found that removing the www from the URL tends to fix the issue but obviously the like counts are different (usually 0).

Strangely when you go to the facebook like button page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and enter the second URL (above) the like button disappears even there.

Have tried so many different things, including stripping all other HTML, CSS and JS off of the page apart from the FB code and still no joy!

Comment: just out of curiousity, whats with the .m extension?

Comment: It is to define that it is a male t-shirt. So .f would be for a female t-shirt, .l for a longsleeved shirt etc. If I done it again I wouldn't do it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is showing up in the debugger with no errors.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chargrilled.co.uk%2Ft-shirts%2FTea-Is-For-Mugs-t-shirt.m

**suggestion:**  urls which appear not to be upto date, run them in the url debugger logged in as the admin account and Facebook will scrape the page for metatags.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

**NOTE:**  If a user adds first like to a button, Facebook could take upto 24 hours to scrape the page or og tags, if an admin creates first like, it is done instantly.  After first like either way, Facebook re-scrapes the page about every 24-72 hours.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've resolved it. The app ID I was using was for an app which did not exist and I'm not the admin for - I guess it has been deleted. I created a new app and ran a few urls through the debugger whilst logged in as the admin and they seem to work ok :)